# How to retrieve the parameters type of my response in spring

Tags: java, spring-boot

I'm trying to retrieve a JSON to the frontend with the types of the parameters.

**Anything like :**

```
{
    "address": "String",
    "role": {
        "admin": 0,
        "user": 1,
        "company": 2
    },
    "level": "String",
    "surname": "String",
    "imageUrl": "String",
    "name": "String",
    "birthDate": "Date",
    "email": "String"
}
```

**Now i can retrieve this:**

```
{
    "address": "String",
    "role": "Role",
    "level": "String",
    "surname": "String",
    "imageUrl": "String",
    "name": "String",
    "birthDate": "Date",
    "email": "String"
}
```

**To do this i'm using:**

```
public Map<String, String> getTypesOfObjectAttributes(Object o) {

        Map<String, String> fields = new HashMap<>();

        Class<?> clazz = o.getClass();

        for (Field field : clazz.getDeclaredFields()) {
            String[] type = field.getType().toString().split("\\.");
            fields.put(field.getName(), type[type.length - 1]);

        }
        return fields;
    }
```

And this code is used by the endpoint to retrieve a JSON.

**Can you help me to retrieve all available values of my enum Role??**

```
public enum Role {
    admin,
    user,
    company;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call [`getEnumConstants()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getEnumConstants--) to see if it is an `enum`, *and* to get the enum values.

If there are enum constants, insert a nested `Map` instead of the type string.

Like this:

```java
public static Map<String, Object> getTypesOfObjectAttributes(Class<?> clazz) {
    Map<String, Object> fields = new HashMap<>();
    for (Field field : clazz.getDeclaredFields()) {
        Object[] enumConstants = field.getType().getEnumConstants();
        if (enumConstants != null) {
            Map<String, Object> enums = new LinkedHashMap<>();
            for (Object enumConstant : enumConstants) {
                Enum<?> e = (Enum<?>) enumConstant;
                enums.put(e.name(), e.ordinal());
            }
            fields.put(field.getName(), enums);
        } else {
            String[] type = field.getType().toString().split("\\.");
            fields.put(field.getName(), type[type.length - 1]);
        }
    }
    return fields;
}
```

*Test*

```java
System.out.println(getTypesOfObjectAttributes(Foo.class));
```

```java
public class Foo {
    String address;
    Role role;
    String level;
    String surname;
    String imageUrl;
    String name;
    Date birthDate;
    String email;
}
```

```java
public enum Role {
    admin,
    user,
    company;
}
```

*Output*

```
{address=String, role={admin=0, user=1, company=2}, level=String, surname=String, imageUrl=String, name=String, birthDate=Date, email=String}
```